# Conditional expectation: why does $\mathbb{E}[g(X)Y \mid X] = g(X) \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]$ hold?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

A property of conditional expectation is that

$$
\mathbb{E}[g(X)Y \mid X] = g(X) \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]
$$

Why is this true? Since we are conditioning on a random variable $X$, it seems non-intuitive that you can pull out $g(X)$ from the calculation of the conditional expectation.

Comment: The intuition is that when you condition on $X$, you are saying that the value of $X$ is "known".  So then the value of $g(X)$ is also "known", and thus it behaves like a constant and can be pulled out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Z$ is $\mathcal G-$ measurable, then 
$$\mathbb E[ZX\mid \mathcal G]=Z\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G] \ \ a.s.$$

**Proof**

Let $G\in \mathcal G$. Then,
$$\mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[ZX\mid \mathcal G]\boldsymbol 1_G\big]=\mathbb E[XZ\boldsymbol 1_G]=\mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]Z\boldsymbol 1_G\big].\tag{*}$$
The second equality comes from the fact that $Z\boldsymbol 1_G$ is $\mathcal G-$measurable. The claim follow since $(*)$ hold for all $G\in \mathcal G$.

Comment: It seems that using the fact that $Z1_G$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable gives a circular argument.

Comment: It doesn't. You should check the definition of conditional expectation. @RobertW.

Comment: Clearly, the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra) gives the first equality. However, I'm not sure about the second equality.

Comment: By definition, for all $U$ being $\mathcal G-$measurable, $\mathbb E[XU]=\mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]U\big]$. Since $U:=Z\boldsymbol 1_G$ is $\mathcal G-$measurable, the last equality follow. @RobertW.

Comment: I see. This trivially follows from the wiki's definition (with $U=1_G$).

Comment: what trivially follows from wiki's definition ?@RobertW.

Comment: That $\mathbb{E}[XU]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]U]$ for any $\mathcal{G}$-measurable $U$.